# "sudo apt-get -f install" not working at all and is causing soo many problems!

Tags: software-center

Just recently I fixed my wireless driver for my laptop which is running 14.04 LTS but now the connection keeps on dropping.  So I looked around and found out that you could try to update your kernel, which I attempted to do. When it showed up in the software center it said that the dependencies were not met or something like that.

Then, I decided to use the software updater to see if that would solve the problem.  THIS is where everything went wrong.  When I went to the software center it said something about repairing because of some problems.  I clicked repair and it gave me an error.  After this, Firefox wasn't opening, at all. And trying to download another browser didn't work either since the software center had, yet another problem... I clicked the little red thing and it said to run "sudo apt-get -f install"

When I run the command i get,

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  account-plugin-windows-live libupstart1
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  unity
The following packages will be upgraded:
  unity
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,510 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 200381 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../unity_7.2.5+14.04.20150521.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking unity (7.2.5+14.04.20150521.1-0ubuntu1) over (7.2.4+14.04.20141217-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): cannot copy archive member from '/var/cache/apt/archives/unity_7.2.5+14.04.20150521.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb' to decompressor pipe: failed to read (Input/output error)
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: unexpected end of input
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/unity_7.2.5+14.04.20150521.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/lib/compiz/libunityshell.so' to '/usr/lib/compiz/libunityshell.so.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
kong@kong-Satellite-C75D-B:~$ sudo apt-get check
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unity : Depends: libunity-core-6.0-9 (= 7.2.4+14.04.20141217-0ubuntu1) but 7.2.5+14.04.20150521.1-0ubuntu1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
kong@kong-Satellite-C75D-B:~$ -f
-f: command not found
kong@kong-Satellite-C75D-B:~$ apt-get -f install
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
kong@kong-Satellite-C75D-B:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  account-plugin-windows-live libupstart1
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  unity
The following packages will be upgraded:
  unity
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,510 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 200381 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../unity_7.2.5+14.04.20150521.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking unity (7.2.5+14.04.20150521.1-0ubuntu1) over (7.2.4+14.04.20141217-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): cannot copy archive member from '/var/cache/apt/archives/unity_7.2.5+14.04.20150521.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb' to decompressor pipe: failed to read (Input/output error)
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: unexpected end of input
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/unity_7.2.5+14.04.20150521.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/lib/compiz/libunityshell.so' to '/usr/lib/compiz/libunityshell.so.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/unity_7.2.5+14.04.20150521.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Anybody know what I should do?  And should I just install a different version of ubuntu since it seems like this one is filled with problems for my PC.

Comment: Have you tried also running: `sudo apt-get install -f`?

Comment: Yes, I have and get the same results.

Comment: And you have also tried running, before that, this: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`? And upgrading any packages which need upgrading?

Comment: I ran the command and it seemed like everything was working fine until it said "You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these"                                           Which results in the same error above.  How do I upgrade package?  I'm very new to ubuntu.

Comment: Have you tried running: `sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean`?

Comment: Darn.. It gives the same error.  "You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these"  and it said that I have unmet dependencies.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? And did you download it from the official Ubuntu website?

Comment: I'm running 14.04 LTS (64 bit) and yes, I got it from the official website.

Comment: I am not sure what is wrong with your system, but if it happened to me, personally I would just do a fresh install to avoid the hassle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked around and found out that I just needed to delete the previous package. When I ran it again, it worked perfectly.

Comment: please mention what steps you did exactly and what package you meant to delete so the other users could take a profit of your answer if they happen to be in your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Test this:

Switch on your computer.

Press and hold the Shift key, which will bring up the `Grub menu`.

Select the line which starts with `Advanced options`.

Select the line ending with `recovery mode`

Your PC should display a menu with a number of options.

Select In this order: `Network`  -- `Drop to root shell prompt`.

In the terminal run:

```
    mount -o remount,rw /
    mount --all
    rm /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb
    apt-get update
    apt-get remove --purge libunity-core-6.0-9
    apt-get install --reinstall unity 
    apt-get dist-upgrade
    apt-get -f install
    reboot
```

## [Source](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/en/man8/apt-get.8.html)